# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Required property docTypeVersion not found for class java.util.Optional

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

When i try to select some part of couchbase document using a dto class,getting this error.
I tried several possible solutions like changing return type of query method `Optional<ResponseDto>` and getting from `Optional` class but did not fixed.I dont understand why it look for `'docTypeVersion'` in `Optional` class.I did not try to get `docTypeVersion` from `Optional` class.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Required property docTypeVersion not found for class java.util.Optional; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required property docTypeVersion not found for class java.util.Optional
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository
@Scope("efatura_islem")
@Collection("gib_thread_process_non_verified")
public interface ThreadProcessCouchbaseRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<ThreadProcessCouchbaseEntity, String> {

    @Query("SELECT meta(gtp).id AS __id , gtp.doc_type_version FROM gib_thread_process_non_verified AS gtp WHERE gtp.zip_path=$documentInstanceIdentifier")
    ResponseDto selectApplicationResponseInfo(String documentInstanceIdentifier);
}
```

DTO class:

```
@Data
@Document
public class ResponseDto implements Serializable {
   
    @Field("doc_type_version")
    private String docTypeVersion;
}
```

Document is below that:

```
{
  "_class": "tr.gov.gib.efatura.core.entity.couchbase.ThreadProcessCouchbaseEntity",
  "calc_hash": "6DB58D42B042F975A7E68464C8E18FE5",
  "client": "10.233.92.0",
  "doc_date_time": "2023-08-09T19:24:53",
  "doc_type": "SYSTEMENVELOPE",
  "doc_type_version": "1.2",
  "error": "ZARF_BASARIYLA_ISLENDI",
  "issue_date": "2023-08-09",
  "gib_elements": [
    {
      "element_type": "APPLICATIONRESPONSE",
      "fKey": "20548227-BDB9-4A7E-B873-FB7B8E3E2BCB",
      "item_count": 1,
      "oid": "31ll52grm01001"
    }
  ],
 
  "header_version": "1.0",
  "state_code": "1200",
  "zip_path": "20548227-BDB9-4A7E-B873-FB7B8E3E2BCB.zip"
}
```

And metadata is below that:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "id": "20548227-BDB9-4A7E-B873-FB7B8E3E2BCB",
    "rev": "1178-177a01ea20e300000000000002000000",
    "expiration": 0,
    "flags": 33554432,
    "type": "json"
  },
  "xattrs": {}
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it, any chance you could share a pubilc repo with that specific problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you and making the return type optional did not work for me. Making it List works, however when you know that you are selecting a unique document, you dont want to retrieve in a list.
You are using the entity class in your repo and trying to retrieve it as a dto. One solution is, make repo use your dto class. Modify it like this:

```
@Repository
@Scope("efatura_islem")
@Collection("gib_thread_process_non_verified")
public interface ThreadProcessCouchbaseRepository extends CouchbaseRepository< ResponseDto, String> {

    @Query("SELECT meta(gtp).id AS __id , gtp.doc_type_version FROM gib_thread_process_non_verified AS gtp WHERE gtp.zip_path=$documentInstanceIdentifier")
    ResponseDto selectApplicationResponseInfo(String documentInstanceIdentifier);
}
```

If you dont want to modify your repo, or write a seperate one for the dto, you should make your dto extend the entity class like this:

```
@Data
@Document
public class ResponseDto extends ThreadProcessCouchbaseEntity {...}
```

Then you will not need to use Optional or List. It worked for me, i hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for help.It worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Required property docTypeVersion not found for class java.util.Optional; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required property docTypeVersion not found for class java.util.Optional"

The stack trace is always useful - it might shed some insight into why the framework thinks the result should be an Optional.

Also - shouldn't the query methods return a List/Iterator/Optional? In case there is zero (or more than one) matching results?  Maybe the framework assumes Optional if you have specified just DTO (just speculating).